# Browser extension to detect misspelled words/typos

Tags: web-browser, language

I'm searching a nice browser extension to detect misspelled words/typos:

- preferably work in Chrome/Chromium
- clearly show the typos/wrong words on the page
- have the functionality to add words to a dictionary (maybe the detected words are not typos but they are correct)
- should be open-source (but I'm open to test any other working extensions)

Any ideas?

Comment: [Doesn't Chrome already have a spell checker](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en)?

Comment: @Timmy *Do you type too fast? Google Chrome's built-in spell-checker automatically checks your spelling in web forms and text fields.* -- I'm not talking here about typing text in textareas/inputs, but see the typos in any part of any rendered page.

Comment: You can use the `edit page` JS bookmarklet. Huey already posted it in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Webpage Spell-Check](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-spell-check/mgdhaoimpabdhmacaclbbjddhngchjik)

Checks spelling on entire page as requested (not only in text fields)

## However, Chrome [already has a spell checker](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en)

[image: descript]

Simply find a text field and start typing to activate it.

### Features

- Clearly shows the typos/errors on the page (underlines them with a a wavy red line)
- Works in Chrome (surprise!)
- Allows adding of words to custom dictionary (just right click)

However, it is not open-source. I believe [a spell-check is in the works in Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/automaticspellingcorrection) however, which is open source. You might want to check that out.

**If you happen to be disatisfied with the native spell-check for some reason, the following alternatives are available**

## [Spell Checker For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg?hl=en)

> This is a spell checker extension for Chrome.
> It's easy to use and fast.
> This extension supports 12 languages for spell check. It's a tool to check spellings of words and come up with suggestions for misspelled words.

[image: zzz]

## [Grammarly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-spell-checker-g/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen?hl=en)

> The free Spell Checker & Grammar Checker by Grammarly helps you write clearly and confidently on Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, Tumblr, and nearly anywhere else on the Web. With Grammarly, you can always be sure that your words are mistake-free and say what you mean.

[image: grammarly]

## To spell-check the entire page

Chrome doesn't officially support this and I don't know of any extensions that do this. Instead, you could copy-paste the contents into a text box, or use this script:

```
javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0
```

Run that on any page you want to spell-check. You can even add it as a bookmarklet if you like for easy access (before & after pics below).

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: But how do I highlight the spelling errors on the whole page, not only in textareas?

Comment: Making the page editable is not a good solution. It is not memory friendly, nor user friendly.

Comment: @IonicăBizău see top portion of answer

Comment: Combined with Grammarly, it makes sense and life easier. :) Thanks!